# FirebaseUser.updatePassword() throws exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Android app which uses Firebase, and I'm trying to change my code from the old Firebase API to the new one. The app uses sign in via email/password.

I'm having trouble with:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String newPassword = "SOME-SECURE-PASSWORD";

user.updatePassword(newPassword)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User password updated.");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    });
```

This produces:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured.
>   [ MISSING_PASSWORD ]

I haven't managed to find any documentation on this particular type of error, and I can't work out why it's happening.

Other similar operations seem to work ok, e.g. `updateEmail()`

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem with `updatePassword()`?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to be working for me. Could you check and see if this occurs for different accounts, and also different passwords, or is one account (or password) the one that is giving you problems?

Comment: I tried different accounts and different passwords, but I keep getting the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: I should have mentioned before that I have also been getting an error: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"  This error comes just before the missing password error. I've made sure that email/password is enabled as a sign in provider on the console.

Comment: Thanks for trying again. The ModuleDescriptor message should not affect this. We are going to have to look into your case in detail. 
Could you please reach out via our [internal support form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/?hl=en), mentioning to send the case to me, with your firebase project number and a longer code snippet (ideally the same exact code that you are using), please?

Comment: OK, I'll do that. Thanks for assistance with this.

Comment: Have you got a solution @CKP78, I am also getting same error

Comment: It turned out to be a bug at Firebase's end. They've fixed it now, though - I'm no longer getting this error. You could try updating your gradle dependencies? I'm using 9.2.0 for each of database, core, auth, and storage.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use like this work fine maybe you can give some error log